# Addition on well ordered sets not-commutative by showing $[0,1) +_o \mathbb{N} =_o \mathbb{N} \neq_o \mathbb{N} +_o [0,1)$

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, ordinals

My goal is to show that addition on well ordered sets are non-commutative by showing that,

$[0,1) +_o \mathbb{N}  =_o \mathbb{N} \neq_o \mathbb{N} +_o [0,1)$

Some definitions (let A and B be posets)

- $[n,m) =_{df} \{k\in \mathbb{N}: n \leq k \land k < m\}$
- $A =_o B \Leftrightarrow_{df} \exists \ \phi : A \to B $ such that
  $\phi$ is bijective and preserves order
- $A+_o B =_{df} \{0\}\times A \cup \{1\}\times B$ with $(i,x),(j,y)   
     \in A+_o B$, $(i,x) \leq_{A+_o B} (j,y) \Leftrightarrow_{df} i < j   
     \lor [i=j=0 \land x \leq_A y] \lor [i=j=1 \land x \leq_B y] $

I also take for granted (ie proved earlier) that sum of two wosets is a woset

I think I've found a order preserving bijection:

$\phi:[0,1)  +_o \mathbb{N} \to\mathbb{N} $ by $\phi((0,0)) = 0,\ \phi((1,n)) = n+1$

$\phi(x) =\phi(y) \implies \phi(x) = 0 =\phi(y) = 0 \implies x = (0,0) = y$
or 
$\phi(x) =\phi(y) \implies \phi(x) = \phi((0,n)) = \phi((0,m)) \implies n + 1 = m+1 \implies x = y $ and in my mind it's clearly onto $\mathbb{N}$ since every natural number $n$ gets hit by either $(0,0)$ or $(1,n-1)$.

Order preserving.

Let $(i,n), (j,m) \in [0,1)  +_o \mathbb{N} $ such that $(i,n) \leq_{[0,1)  +_o \mathbb{N}} (j,m)$

- Case 1.) $i< j$,

  $(i,n) \leq_{[0,1)  +_o \mathbb{N}} (j,m) \implies (i,n) = (0,0)
     \land (j,m) = (1,m) \implies \phi((i,n)) = \phi((0,0)) = 0
     \leq_{\mathbb{N}} \phi((j,m)) = \phi((1,m)) = m+1
     \geq_\mathbb{N} 1  $
- Case 2.) $i = j = 0$

  If $i = j = 0$ then $(i,n) \leq_{[0,1)  +_o \mathbb{N}} (j,m)
     \implies (i,n) = (j,m) = (0,0) \implies \phi((i,n)) = \phi((j,m)) = 0
     \implies \phi((i,n))  \leq_{\mathbb{N}}\phi((j,m)) $   Since $[0,1) =
     \{0\}$
- Case 3.) $i = j = 1$

  If $i = j = 0$ then $(i,n) =(1,n) \leq_{[0,1)  +_o \mathbb{N}}
     (j,m)=(1,m)$ then we have that $n \leq_{\mathbb{N}} m  \implies
     \phi((i,n)) = \phi((1,n)) = n+1 \leq_{\mathbb{N}} \phi((i,m)) =
     \phi((1,m)) = m+1  $

Here I draw the conclusion that $[0,1) +_o \mathbb{N}  =_o \mathbb{N} $

But now to the part which I find very challenging. I have to show that $\mathbb{N} \neq_o \mathbb{N} +_o [0,1)$

I think I can find a bijection $\pi: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} +_o [0,1)$ by $\pi(0) = (1,0), \pi(n) = (0,n+1)$ but I can't get it to "break" with the order preserving.
I've also tried to play around with just some general bijection but without any luck.

My idea is to find a bijection $\pi: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} +_o [0,1)$ (maybe a general one if that might work) assume or explicitly show that is has order. take two elements $a,b$ from $\mathbb{N} +_o [0,1)$ such that $a \leq_{\mathbb{N} +_o [0,1)} b$ and then map them to $\mathbb{N}$ thus we have $\pi(a),\pi(b) \in \mathbb{N} $ Since every element in  $\mathbb{N}$ is mapped from some element in $[0,1) +_o \mathbb{N}$ we can rewrite $\pi(a) =\phi((i,n)),\pi(b) =\phi((j,m))$ and then deriving a contradiction so that $\pi$ can't preserve order.
This at best a very very dirty sketch and I have several problems.

By intuition I refuse to believe that there is no bijective mapping from $\leq_{\mathbb{N} +_o [0,1)}$  to $\mathbb{N}$.

If I find a bijection and derive the contradiction, I have to show that this bijection is unique, right? I find this to be quite impossible to be honest.

Or am I going about this the wrong way, is it specifically the mapping of strict ordering that fails in some way I'm missing? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I strongly dislike the notation, so will not use it. But the well-ordered set on the right seems to have a largest element, while $\mathbb{N}$ doesn't, so there can't be an order-preserving bijection. (That's usually the way one proves the non-existence of a structure-preserving bijection: show that there is a property preserved by such a bijection that one structure has and the other doesn't.)

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you very much!

Comment: Does the downvoter please care to explain what I did wrong? Did I break any written or unwritten rule in my question? Not enough effort shown?

Comment: There is a much larger amount of effort shown than usual. Downvotes often have no rational justification. That is the case here.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Wouldn't it be better to provide answers in the answers area? This would show others that it is not necessary to deal with the question in detail.

Comment: @Keinstein: Except in the case of hints for very much homework-style questions, I usually want to provide full detail, in a style consistent with OP's, with minor explicit gaps. Proving that appending a one point set to $\mathbb{N}$ on the left is different from appending on the right seems at most worth three or four lines, using a quite different style. And "order isomorphism preserves order-theoretic properties" feels like a comment, not a full answer.

Comment: I've find your questions because I think I've read the same book as you, Notes on set theory, isn't it? So I think André Nicolas you might discuss the notation with Moschovakis hahaha

Comment: By the way, I'm trying to do this exercise, I will post my answer if I found out something :)

Comment: Addition of well-ordered sets as defined here is basically addition of ordinal numbers, so I think that the tag (ordinals) is appropriate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $\mathbb{N} \neq_o \mathbb{N} +_o [0,1)$. We'll show by **contradiction**. Suppose that it exists an order preserving bijection $$\rho: \mathbb{N} \longrightarrow \mathbb{N} +_o [0,1).$$ Then, it must exist an element $m\in \mathbb{N} $ such that $\rho(m)=(1,0)$. But as $\mathbb{N}$ doesn't have a maximum element, we can affirm  that $m+1$ exists. The image of $m+1$ would have the form $$\rho(m+1)=(0,x), x\in \mathbb{N}$$ and so $\rho(m+1)\leq_{\mathbb{N} +_o [0,1)}\rho(m)$, which is a contradiction because $\rho$ is order preserving.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you. :)